# .Net Raw String Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I am developing a .NET Wep API project using Entity Framework. I couldn't write a query with an entity for this SQL code:

```
select 
    count(*) as total, 
    dateadd(day, 0, datediff(day, 0, Plandate)) as created
from 
    Task 
where 
    AssignedUserId = 3 
    and (PlanDate between '2021-07-01' and '2021-07-31 23:59')
group by 
    dateadd(day, 0, datediff(day, 0, PlanDate))
```

Here's how I wrote it with a raw query:

```
var a = db.Task.SqlQuery("select count(*) as total, DATEADD(DAY,0, datediff(day,0,Plandate)) as created from Task where AssignedUserId = 3 and(PlanDate between '2021-07- 01' and '2021-07-31 23:59') group by dateadd(DAY, 0, datediff(day, 0, PlanDate))").ToList();
```

but I am getting this error:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: 'The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'CRMSFAData.Model.Task'. A member of the type, 'id', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.'

I tried to write with entity:

```
var query = from t in db.Task
            where (t.AssignedUserId == userId && (t.PlanDate <= sd && t.PlanDate >= ed))
            group t by new { t.PlanDate } into grouping
            select new
                {
                    c = grouping.Count(),
                    grouping.Key.PlanDate
                };

return query.ToList();
```

This returns an empty result set.

Is there any other solution with entity or raw query? Can you help me?

Comment: _"but I am getting this error:"_ - [The SQL query must return data for all properties of the entity type.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#limitations)

Comment: Also what  are `sd` and `ed` in the LINQ query?

Comment: In your Linq statement, you need to group by date only to have the same query. Off the top of my head, I think `group by t.PlanDate.Date into grouping` will work.

Comment: Just a side note:  rather than dateadd(day, 0, datediff(day, 0, Plandate))  how about convert(date,Plandate)  ?

Comment: @GuruStron sd: StartDate, ed:EndDate.  Unfortunately I am not developing with .Net Core. This is why I can't use FromSqlRaw.

Comment: @johnCappelletti The convert(date,Plandate) code doesn't work for me because I'm grouping by day.

Comment: @DavidG i tried but it didn't work

Comment: @ozzmhmt I get that... both would be convert.   Just seems to be an odd route to go.  :)

Comment: @ozzmhmt try changing your date comparasion to `(t.PlanDate >= sd && t.PlanDate <= ed)`

Answer (score 0):

"db.Task.SqlQuery()" return  collection of Tasks. but your query select another columns: " a number as count and a datetime as created " . you have two solution

1- based on to your EF version you can use DbContext.Database.SqlQuery() or an a thing like this.
2- create a view in database and map to EF entity model in "OnModelCreating" method in dbcontext :

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<ViewModel>(eb =>
                       {
                           eb.HasNoKey();
                           eb.ToView("ViewName");
                       });
```